# Server languageserver.coc-clangd failed to start: Error: invalid params of initialize: expected array for /workspaceFolders

Tags: vim, clang++, neovim

I loaded up a normal cpp file, and this is what I'm getting.
I've tried `:CocUpdate` and other commands such as `:CocInstall coc-clangd` but nothing works.

[image]

Here's my `settings.json`

[image]

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker or dedicated support channels.

Comment: I have done an extensive search but nothing works

Comment: You know you can open issues, right?

Comment: Yeah I have already, as of now I've removed the plugin from my config

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.ccls` file in the project root folder.

Example for `.ccls` file (basic):

```
clang++

%h %cpp -std=c++17
```